# Early Parsed Low Variable inside Channel Tags

Tags: parse-order, low-variables

I have a couple Low Variables I'm using similar to the traditional `embed` template method. This variable has `query` module tag to find prev/next entry, but since it's within the `channel` tag I'm having issues getting the early parsed LV code to output the correct info - which I thought would take care of it.

So I then thought "why don't I take the `query` tag code and create a new LV that is parsed earlier than it's parent LV.

I'm pretty sure this is a parsing stage issue. So I was wondering if this is even possible since the LV is inside the `channel` tag? I also moved around the variables to different LV groups to change the parsing sequence, but that didn't work.

My coded simplified is like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="case_studies"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    require_entry="yes"
}
    ...
    {lv_tmpl_utility_belt}
    ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

`{lv_tmpl_utility_belt}`:

```
<div id="utility-belt"{if segment_1 != ""} class="nav-sticky"{/if}>
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_1}" parse="inward"}
    {case value=""} {!-- Show Home Utility Bar --}
        <ul id="nav-belt-tabs" class="wrapper clearfix">
            {exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_home_hero"}
                <li{if count == 1} class="active"{/if}><a href="#">{hero_tab}</a></li>
            {/exp:low_variables:pair}
        </ul>
    {/case}

    {case default="yes"} {!-- Show Interior Utility Bar --}
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a class="btn-flat btn-menu"href="#">Navigation Menu</a>

        {lv_ee_casestudy_prevnext_entries}

    </div>
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee} 
</div> {!-- /#utility-belt --}
```

`{lv_ee_casestudy_prevnext_entries}`:

```
{exp:query sql="
    SELECT 
        url_title, 
        title 
    FROM exp_channel_titles 
    WHERE url_title < '{segment_3}'
    AND channel_id = '3'
    AND status = 'open'
    ORDER BY url_title 
    DESC LIMIT 1
"}
<a class="btn-flat btn-prev" href="{url_title}" title="Previous: {title}">Previous Case Study</a>
{/exp:query}

{exp:query sql="
    SELECT 
        url_title, 
        title 
    FROM exp_channel_titles 
    WHERE url_title > '{segment_3}'
    AND channel_id = '3'
    AND status = 'open'
    ORDER BY url_title 
    ASC LIMIT 1
"}
<a class="btn-flat btn-next" href="{url_title}" title="Next: {title}">Next Case Study</a>
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Just a quick note, unrelated to answering your question but important none the less:- the query module does not escape input, so by passing `{segment_3}`(or other dynamic content) into your query param you're opening a potential SQL injection vulnerability. Check out the [Active Record](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/activerecord) plugin for a safer alternative.

Comment: I'm not 100% positive, but I don't think that's an issue b/c you can't use semicolons, apostrophes, slashes, etc. in URL's w/o getting an error. Will that query work with the Active record plugin? I don't see support for `AND`?

Comment: What version of EE are you using and what version of Low Variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using early parsed vars only, try putting both of them in the **same** LV group and make sure `{lv_tmpl_utility_belt}` comes **before** `{lv_ee_casestudy_prevnext_entries}`. This ensures that the vars will be put into the template correctly. Having the second var above the first will fail.

To clarify, you've got 2 vars, A and B. A *contains* B, so A needs to be parsed *before* B. Hence the order in their group matters.

However, looking at the contents of your vars, I can see an issue coming up. You've got `{title}` and `{url_title}` vars inside the Query tags. These will actually get parsed by the channel:entries tag before the Query tag can get to it. So, you either need to rename those, or, to avoid such conflicts altogether, you could use the low_variables:single tag, along with the `preparse:` parameters, **available in LV 2.3.0+**.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="case_studies"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    require_entry="yes"
}
    ...
    {exp:low_variables:single
        var="lv_tmpl_utility_belt"
        preparse:segment_1="{segment_1}"
        preparse:segment_3="{segment_3}"
    }
    ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And just change the `lv_tmpl_utility_belt` var slightly, so it calls `lv_ee_casestudy_prevnext_entries` by also using the low_variables:single tag:

```
{exp:low_variables:single
    var="lv_ee_casestudy_prevnext_entries"
    preparse:segment_3="{segment_3}"
}
```

This approach is what some people call [Killing the Embed Tag](http://leereamsnyder.com/blog/low-variables-230-totally-killed-the-embed-tag).

Comment: I just converted an existing site from embeds to this method last week and it works perfectly.

Comment: Low thanks for the tips and thorough answer. I was confused on how the use the `preparse` parameters before, but now this makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Question: Can you explain why I need `preparse:segment_3="{segment_3}"` in the parent template? Does this pass this through from `lv_tmpl_utility_belt` to `lv_ee_casestudy_prevnext_entries` variable? I noticed when I removed it from the parent template (ie. `channels` tag call) it stopped working properly. Just trying to understand and learn how this approach works

Comment: Because of parse order. The `{segment_x}` variables are parsed before the LV tags/vars are put into the template and thus remain unparsed, unless you pass them through using the preparse parameter.